# Keyboard layout (OS X) - write a sentence with one character

Tags: macos, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, limit, keyboard-layout

I am a web developer and use git and other small commands all the time in terminal. I know git goodies, how to use aliases, etc., but I was wondering whether it is possible to do it with keyboard layouts?
(1. Just for fun, 2. There might be other uses of it)
I managed to create keylayout file and substitute a character by a word, but I cannot get further than 20 (or so) characters. Does somebody know whether there is some limit on it? I played with maxout variable but it had no effect.

I hope I was clear on my question, might be a bit abstract. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2056/_index.html

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you ended up figuring this out, but I'm right there with you—couldn't figure out a solution, trying to input 30 or so keys seems to crash whatever application is open, and relaunch Finder. Bit of a shame, although you could try using text replacement? It's under System Preferences > Keyboard > Text, I've been using that for misc things that I was too lazy to slap on my keyboard.

Key replacement doesn't seem to have a limit, although it might and I just didn't notice. Bit of a bummer, seeing as I'd prefer to hit "Alt-B" instead of typing something like :replaceme:, but it seems to get the job done. Doing some quick testing revealed no problems outputting 2,000 chars via text replacement, although after that it seems to hit some sort of limit (2048, maybe). For now, though, this seems to be the best solution.